# moveit change pick pipeline

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know if it is possible to change the pipeline for the pick action (I'm working with ROS Melodic)

I need to customise the "post_grasp_retreat" stage to execute something like a trajectory instead of a linear movement.

Is there an "easy" way to change only this section of the pipeline, or I need to rewrite the whole action?

Thanks,
Germán

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359098/moveit-change-pick-pipeline/) by [gecastro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7526/gecastro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course you can change the stage if you edit the sources...

The much more general approach by some of us Maintainers is the [MoveIt Task Constructor framework](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_task_constructor) which is designed for users to implement their own stages.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gecastro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7526/gecastro/) on 2020-08-10**:
Thanks, I'll have a look